# HTTP 500 errors with the php Google API client

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I want to get the data from google sheet in json format. I have implemented the code but it giving error is

> page currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500

I am using this link "https://gist.github.com/karlkranich/de225928665dc6b83667". The function checkServiceAccountCredentialsFile() given in this file was not defined anywhere in base.php file. So i coppy the base.php file from "github google client php".

When i echo this function in my php file from where i am trying to get the data is not working.

please suggest anything to resolve this issue.

Comment: I followed these links to create the project in google api console.

Comment: http://karl.kranich.org/2015/04/16/google-sheets-api-php/

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/google-spreadsheets-and-php.html